# Highlight character range in .NET TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

is there an easy possibility to highlight a portion of text in a normal WinForms TextBox (I cannot use RichTextBox in this case). All the solutions I came up with so far are very complex and handle drawing the text on their own, including fancy Interop calls...

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I don't talk about selecting the text but highlighting parts of it with a background color or a colored underline. Thanks again

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight a portion"? Selecting the portion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up implementing the behavior on my own. 
http://www.codedblog.com/2007/09/17/owner-drawing-a-windowsforms-textbox/ was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to change the color or font style of part of the text in a regular `TextBox` control, there is no support for that. What you *can* do is to select a portion of the text to make it stand out, but that is obviously a very temporary solution (note that the `HideSelection` property must be set to `false` for this to show when the `TextBox` does not have focus):

```
// select the 8 characters, starting after the fifth character
myTextBox.Select(5, 8);
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I found out, too

Answer (score 0):

Set the following properties

```
TextBox1.SelectionStart = 10
TextBox1.SelectionLength = 8
```